# Ruby Object Mapper documentation

Tags: ruby, orm, rom

I need to use an ORM for my project and I opted to use ROM, since every other ORM seems to be directly tied to Rails and I am not using and will not use Rails.

I find the official documentation of ROM, found on [www.rom-rb.org](http://www.rom-rb.org), to be awful. It doesn't provide any minimal code examples or even a cohesive experience. Instead, it gives you multitudes of theoretical breadcrumbs that are completely unrelated to each other. After reading the entire documentation under the "Learn" section, I realised my knowledge of ROM did not change in the slightest.

I need help from developers who have experience with ROM. Is there an actual source of knowledge on how to use ROM? Where can I find code examples or projects that use ROM? Or is there a good alternative ORM in Ruby that isn't tied to Rails?

Comment: "Or is there a good alternative ORM in Ruby that isn't tied to Rails?" – Resource requests are off-topic on [so]. However, there are plenty of ORMs in Ruby that are not tied to Rails. The most widely-used one is probably ActiveRecord, which you may have heard of. The second most popular, I believe, is Sequel. DataMapper was also popular at one point, but it is no longer being developed, or more precisely, there was a big rewrite named DataMapper 2 that was never released, and there was another big rewrite that then became ROM.

Comment: Use ActiveRecord directly or use Sequel. Using some odd-bird ORM is only asking for dismay down the road when it inevitably gets abandoned.

Comment: @JörgWMittag RIP DataMapper. It had some neat ideas.

Comment: Selecting low bus-factor tools is a great way to cause yourself pain and suffering. If you choose software that's not popular or mainline, then you need to roll up your sleeves and read the source code. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some recommendations from the comments to the question, I decided to ditch ROM in favour of Sequel. It really turned out to be much simpler and, most importantly, to actually work.

It is quite ironic that ROM is in part based on Sequel...

Comment: Sequel is just a driver. ROM helps with maintainability and really hammers home the separation of concerns and aids in enforcing SRP (single responsibility principle) from the SOLID acronym. Perhaps worth revisiting once you realize that you're littering your application code with data access code using Sequel. If you're doing something tiny and not meant to be maintained, just use the driver/toolkit of Sequel directly